# Error while importing web package in windows

Tags: python, importerror, web.py

I installed web.py using cmd, it got successfully installed.

```
C:\Users\Admin1>pip install web.py==0.40.dev0
Requirement already satisfied: web.py==0.40.dev0 in c:\users\admin1\anaconda3\li
b\site-packages\web.py-0.40.dev0-py3.6.egg
```

But when I try to run this command on my python editor
`import web` 
it gives error

`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Any suggestion on what m I missing??
Thanks

Domnick.

Answer (score 0):

ensure you take the correct pip with the right interpreter

```
pip --version
```

and

```
pip3 --version
```

and for anaconda you have a own anaconda prompt, where you can install your packages and list, which packages are installed 
On anaconda prompt:

```
conda list
```

to show your installed anaconda packages.

---

open the anaconda prompt:

type in:

```
conda install -c conda-forge web.py
```

I take the PyCharm IDE:

Under "file" -> "settings" -> Project Interpreter -> select Anaconda Interpreter -> in my case it´s Python3.6.1 (C:\Anaconda3\python.exe)
interpreter located in

```
C:\Anaconda3\python.exe
```

after this settings the import statement

```
import web
```

works absolutely fine for me

Comment: after  using `conda list` the version of web.py is `web.py                    0.40.dev0                 <pip>`

Comment: I was working on python `3.x` I tried changing it to `2.7` now it seems to be working fine.